# How to generate google map code using geocoding?

Tags: google-maps

I have some data about place,road, city.
And I want to search the map by entering these values.
Now I have script that generate latitude and longitude using geocoding.
But I wonder if there is a way to generate google map code (iframe) by geocoding?
Could you please tell me the way or give me some links?

Answer (score 0):

The following example may help you getting started. All you would need to do is to change the JavaScript variable `userLocation` with the place, road and city chosen by your users:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var userLocation = 'London, UK';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark) {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
             map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()));
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```